# Python Flask server with MQTT subscription on_message Not Working

Tags: python, flask, mqtt

I know the on_message only works if mqtt is subscribed to topics but per my debug output it is subscribing to the topics and all that seems to be working but the "on_message" never fires for any messages received.  Not sure what I am missing

**app.py**

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify,render_template
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import time
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/web/log/Frosty_app.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s    %(levelname)s   %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Setup MQTT broker connection
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = '192.168.10.10'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = 'homeassistant'
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = 'Passwsord'
app.config['MQTT_REFRESH_TIME'] = 1.0  # refresh time in seconds
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 30
mqtt = Mqtt(app)

socketio = SocketIO(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

logging.info("MQTT - Connected to Broker " + str(datetime.now()))

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

# Define the GPIO ports that each channel will use.
LIGHT = 4

#Inital set all MQTT to off
mqtt.publish('pool/state/light', 0)

# Setup each of the GPIO Ports
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(LIGHT, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)


mqtt.subscribe('pool/toggle/light')
mqtt.subscribe('pool/status/update')


@mqtt.on_topic('pool/toggle/light')
def handle_mytopic(client, userdata, message):
    with app.app_context():
        status=int(GPIO.input(LIGHT))
        if status == 1 and message.payload.decode() == "off":
            GPIO.output(LIGHT, GPIO.LOW)
            verify_state = GPIO.input(LIGHT)
            mqtt.publish('pool/state/light', verify_state)
            logging.info("MQTT - Light turned off " + str(datetime.now()))
            print("MQTT - Light turned off " + str(datetime.now()))
        elif status== 0 and message.payload.decode() == "on":
            GPIO.output(LIGHT, GPIO.HIGH)
            verify_state = GPIO.input(LIGHT)
            mqtt.publish('pool/state/light', verify_state)
            logging.info("MQTT - Light turned on " + str(datetime.now()))
            print("MQTT - Light turned on " + str(datetime.now()))
        else:
            logging.info("Error Decoding topic" +  str(datetime.now()))
            print("Topic Status: " + str(status) + " Message: " + message.payload.decode() + " - " + str(datetime.now()))


@mqtt.on_topic('pool/status/update')
def handle_mytopic(client, userdata, message):
    with app.app_context():
        light_status=int(GPIO.input(LIGHT))
        mqtt.publish('pool/state/light', light_status)
        logging.info("MQTT Updated state info " + str(datetime.now()))
        print("MQTT Updated state info " + str(datetime.now()))
        
@socketio.on('publish')
def handle_publish(json_str):
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    mqtt.publish(data['topic'], data['message'])
    print('Socket Published')


@socketio.on('subscribe')
def handle_subscribe(json_str):
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    mqtt.subscribe(data['topic'])
    print('Subscribed to: ' + data['topic'])


@socketio.on('unsubscribe_all')
def handle_unsubscribe_all():
    mqtt.unsubscribe_all()
    print('Unsubscribed all')


@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    print('message received')
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode()
    )
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)


@mqtt.on_log()
def handle_logging(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(level, buf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

**log results**

- (1676) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:5000
- 16 Received SUBACK 16

  - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1, m0), 'pool/toggle/light', ...  (3
    bytes)
- Topic Status: 0 Message: off - 2021-09-10 10:33:00.625279 16
  Received SUBACK
- (1676) accepted ('192.168.10.222', 34608) 16 Sending
- PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m4), 'b'pool/toggle/light'', ... (3 bytes)
- Socket Published 16 Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0),
  'pool/toggle/light', ...  (3 bytes)
- Topic Status: 0 Message: off -
  2021-09-10 10:33:04.643604
- 16 Sending UNSUBSCRIBE (d0,
  m5)[b'pool/toggle/light']
- 16 Received UNSUBACK (Mid: 5)  16 Sending
  UNSUBSCRIBE (d0, m6) [b'pool/status/update']
- Unsubscribed all
- 16
  Received UNSUBACK (Mid: 6)
- 16 Sending SUBSCRIBE (d0, m7)
  [(b'pool/toggle/light', 0)]
- Subscribe to: pool/toggle/light
- 16
  Received SUBACK
- 16 Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1,
  m0),'pool/toggle/light', ...  (3 bytes)
- Topic Status: 0 Message: off

  - 2021-09-10 10:33:16.005886
- 16 Sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m8), 'b'pool/toggle/light'', ... (3 bytes)
- Socket Published
- 16 Received
  PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'pool/toggle/light', ...  (3 bytes)
- Topic
  Status: 0 Message: off - 2021-09-10 10:33:30.818603
- 16 Sending
  PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m9), 'b'pool/toggle/light'', ... (3 bytes)
- Socket Published
- 16 Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0,
  m0),'pool/toggle/light', ...  (3 bytes)
- Topic Status: 0 Message: off
- 2021-09-10 10:33:36.593762
- 16 Sending PINGREQ 16 Received PINGRESP

**index.html**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Flask-MQTT example{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
//end new connection

    $('#publish').click(function(event) {
      var topic = $('#topic').val();
      var message = $('#message').val();
      var qos = $('#qos').val();
      var data = '{"topic": "' + topic + '", "message": "' + message + '", "qos": ' + qos + '}';
      socket.emit('publish', data=data);
    });

    $('#subscribe').click(function(event) {
    console.log('Subscribe Clicked');
      var topic = $('#subscribe_topic').val();
      var qos = $('#subscribe_qos').val();
      var data = '{"topic": "' + topic + '", "qos": ' + qos + '}';
      socket.emit('subscribe', data=data);
      $('#subscribe').hide();
      $('#unsubscribe').show();
      $('#subscribe_topic').prop('readonly', true);
    });

    $('#unsubscribe').click(function(event) {
      socket.emit('unsubscribe_all');
      $('#subscribe').show();
      $('#unsubscribe').hide();
      $('#subscribe_topic').prop('readonly', false);
    });

    socket.on('mqtt_message', function(data) {
      console.log('Received Message: ' + data);
      var text = '(' + data['topic'] + ' qos: ' + data['qos'] + ') ' + data['payload'];
      var $textarea = $('#subscribe_messages');
      $textarea.val($textarea.val() + text + '\n');
    })
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Flask-MQTT Example</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Publish MQTT Message</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Topic: </label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="topic" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Message: </label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="message" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Qos: </label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <select id="qos" class="form-control">
                      <option value=0>0</option>
                      <option value=1>1</option>
                      <option value=2>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <button id="publish" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Subscribe MQTT Messages</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Topic:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input id="subscribe_topic" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Qos: </label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <select id="subscribe_qos" class="form-control">
                      <option value=0>0</option>
                      <option value=1>1</option>
                      <option value=2>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <button id="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                    <button id="unsubscribe" class="btn btn-default" style="display:none;">Unsubscribe</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Messages:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <textarea id="subscribe_messages" class="form-control" rows=10></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm probably missing something but cannot see an issue. [`on_message()`](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html#flask_mqtt.Mqtt.on_message) "will not be called if there exists an topic-specific callback added by the on_topic decorator" (and you are using the `on_topic` decorator for the two topics you subscribe to). Your output includes `Topic Status:`... which indicates that your handler for `pool/toggle/light` is being called.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that.  Do you have a good source that explains how all this operates for me?  From everything I read it only said that "on_message" only fired if you were subscribed to a topic and never mentioned what your saying.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: [The docs](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) seem pretty good (but I don't use this library myself).

Comment: Thank you I guess I overlooked that or didn't understand it, probably the latter.  Thanks for the help